# Move a line smoothly across the screen

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm trying to move a red line (stutter-free) across the screen, and I've tried all kinds of different approaches. From GDI+ double-buffering (using the `BufferedGraphics` class) to WPF's `WriteableBitmap`, and all failed. It could be that the timers im using are not accurate enough, it could v-sync tearing, but it just seems impossible. We're in the year 2013 now, and I've got a high-end GPU and still im not able to reproduce something my old 8-bit SNES had no problems with.

Does someone have a WinForms code example that is 100% smooth and flicker-free, or is it just mission impossible without DirectX?

Comment: At 32 Hz so 32 pixels per second

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you may simply animate a Line control.

```
<Canvas>
    <Line x:Name="line"
        X2="{Binding X1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
        Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas}}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4">
    </Line>
</Canvas>
```

You would create and start an animation with a method like this:

```
private void StartAnimation()
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = ActualWidth, // width of the window
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ActualWidth / 32),
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
    };

    line.BeginAnimation(Line.X1Property, animation);
}
```

---

Instead of animating the `X1` property of the Line and let the `X2` property follow by binding, you could also animate the RenderTransform of the Line:

```
<Canvas>
    <Line Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas}}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4">
        <Line.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform"/>
        </Line.RenderTransform>
    </Line>
</Canvas>
```

The StartAnimation method would now look like this:

```
private void StartAnimation()
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = ActualWidth, // width of the window
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ActualWidth / 32),
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
    };

    transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animation);
}
```